# toString() and hashCode() method of Object class in java

Tags: java

If the `toString()` method of the `Object` class returns the hash code of the object, then what does the `hashCode()` method of Object class do?  If it also returns the hash code of the object, then why is the value that is returned by the `toString()` method the same as the value that is returned by the `hashCode()` method ?

Comment: The toString() method does not *just* return the hashcode..

Comment: _why the value that is return by toString() method by the value that is return by the hashCode() method_ Rephrase that please, missing a verb.

Comment: This is clearly a novice question, but it shows some insight.  I think it's being downvoted unfairly.

Answer (score 1):

Object is the base class for all other Java classes.  This means that all classes implicitly support `toString` and `hashCode`.  But many classes override one or both, so they don't get Object's default implementations.

For instance, `toString` of a Double object will return a meaningful default-formatted version of the floating-point number, while `hashCode` of a double will return a hashed version of the float value, suitable for keying searches in a hashtable.

`toString` is intended primarily to support debug printing.  What it returns is whatever the developer felt made the "most sense" for that specific object class.  (For Object there's not much to work with, so the class name in combination with the text representation of the hashCode value is used.)  `hashCode`, on the other hand, is intended to facilitate hash-based searching, and so the developer attempts to produce a number that has a high probability of being different on objects that compare differently, but is guaranteed to be identical on objects that compare as equal.

Answer (score 0):

some points here :

```
toString()
```

returns the className@hashCode

```
hashCode()
```

returns the hashCode only of the class

the hashCode is used for Collections (Sets and Maps), it is a way for java to improve performance while searching in them, i dont know if you know how to use Collections framework or not ! but they work like this

when you try to search for an object in a collection, it starts looking for the hash code of your object , and when it finds a match, it starts searching for an equal object

that way, instead of searching a collection of 1000 objects trying to compare each object with your search, it will search the hash codes (which can be only 50 for example), then it searches the objects with this hash code

there are lots of rules on how to work with equals() and hashCode() methods there, but they are easy any way